# why throw error when call next on a resultset in groovy

Tags: jdbc, groovy

I have the following code in groovy, and I need to control to loop the rows, so that I can split the rows in chucks in pass them to other threads (by actor). but looks like next() can't be called, I didn't the following test

```
def ORACLE = Sql.newInstance( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@.....", "xxx", "xxx", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" )
java.sql.ResultSet rs = ORACLE.executeQuery("select 1 as x from dual")  
rs.next()
```

error:

```
Oct 30, 2012 6:15:44 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement: next
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:242)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following will works: just use java stype jdbc.

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes

driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(".....", "**", "**")  
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dual")  
while (rs.next()){
   println 'xx'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's all your code?  I can't see how that is failing.

Usually, this error is called by trying to open a second `ResultSet` on a single `Statement`, and then calling `next` on the first (now closed) `ResultSet`

Can you try this, and see if it works:

```
ORACLE.eachRow( "select 1 as x from dual" ) { row ->
  println row.x
}
```

Comment: the only missed is the code to import package. If using your approach, there is no error. But I need to use next() to control the work flow. I tried to use mysql, but it also throws the same error.